# iphone - How to limit the number of visible cell in one section

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I have one table with two section and each of them has 7 fix row, as I am using story board I can set my table to static table and fill it statically.

The problem is, It makes me a tall view and user need to scroll over the whole view but I need to change it in a way that each section shows only four row and if user wants to scroll, scroll inside the table area (not the whole view).

here are the pictures:

it is now :

[image]

but I want to be like :

[image]

and when user wants to choose just scroll inside the tables, 
Thank for your help.

Comment: Why not use 2 UITableViews, of 1 section each, one above the other? This way you can add as many rows as you need and resize the tableviews so the user can see only 4 rows without scrolling.

Comment: If I understood you correctly you want for one table 7 rows but visible only 4 rows, so the user has to scroll down for the 3 more rows.. right? I recommend from user experience point of view another option: show the first 4 rows statically and allow the user to drill down by pressing a More button using navigation controller to present the full 7 rows table alone.

Comment: @andreagiavatto , in you suggested way when you have a grouped table and the visible size of table is less that the total height of table (including row) apple just cut the bottom and it will not become good looking.

Comment: @codedad that is one way but because my rows are totally static, i did not want to make code for them. it has to be a simple way for that

Comment: Allright then, maybe you can use a Scroll View and inside it you can have your static TableView. I think it is the only way you can have a kind of masking over a full table list.

Comment: good point let me try and give the feedback

Comment: @codedad as i figure it out it will not work with static table so i used some photoshop trick to make it look like what i wanted. and i used 2 seperate table which handle pragmatically . any way I wanted to thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not use the double scroll view you propose. This is confusing and difficult to use. I strongly advise against the user interface you suggest.

Make the table view dynamic and use the `datasource` protocol.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
 numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
   // return the desired number of rows
}
```

If there are a lot of rows, you can have the section return 0 rows as a default and insert the rows dynamically when the user taps on a section header (use custom section headers for this).

In any case, static table view cells are not feasible.

Comment: If I do not find an answer for using static table with my desire way I will. but imagine you have a table with 3 section : section one has 40 row and section two has 30 row; So the poor user should scroll 70 row done to see if any other section are down there or not. it seems stupid. but if user can see all 3 section in one view and then scroll inside these tables that would be better

Comment: My point exactly. That is why static table view cells are not suitable for this use case. If you have the scenario you describe (with 70 rows), you should segue to another view controller for one specific section. Also, you could use the solution I added to my answer (dynamic sections). Forget about static cells.

Comment: I did same, with some photo shop trick to look it like a static table with 2 section but actually it is 2 separate pragmatically table. tanks any way. and I think I should close this post. so you got it

Answer (score 0):

implement these two methods in your UITableViewController:

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (section == tableView.numberOfSections - 1) {
        return [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1, 1)];
    }
    return nil;
}


- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (section == tableView.numberOfSections - 1) {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

In fact, these codes are telling tableview that you don't need to render the seperator line for me anymore, so that it looks the empty cells won't be displayed(in fact , the empty cell can not be selected too)

Or you can just make the cell style to be group.